# ¿Cómo puedo pedir datos para un array separados por espacios? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy estudiando Javascript y me he topado con un ejercicio el cual me pide que introduzca una serie de números separados por espacios y una vez haya terminado presionando el botón aceptar, almacene dichos valores en un array.

Sé introducir valores en un array siempre y cuando haya definido antes cuántos valores voy a introducir, pero en este caso no sé cómo se hace.

Es importante aclarar que se me solicita realizar el ejercicio haciendo uso de prompt.

Gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar el metodo `split()` sobre un string para obtener un array.

Funciona de la siguiente manera:

```
function stringToArray(){
  var texto = "valor1 valor2 valor3 valor4";
  var array = texto.split(' ');
  console.log(array);
}
```

Pues lo que hace `split()` es dividir una cadena por un separador y guardar los valores divididos en un array resultante, el metodo `split()` recibe el caracter separador. Si fuera una coma sería `split(',')`.

**Edit:**

```
function promptToArray(){
  var texto = prompt("Introduzca los valores separados por espacios:");
  var array = texto.split(' ');
  console.log(array);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero me ha faltado especificar que quiero introducir los valores mediante "prompt". Es decir, que me salga una ventana donde pueda introducir los valores según el usuario y no teniendo que meterlos de manera manual en el propio código.